# How do I forward my page in Javascript if the website can't use "https://"?

Tags: javascript, html, url, https, forward

So I have a button that will forward the page to a website like this example.tk, but it keeps on thinking that I just want to go to ./example.tk inside the website folder where it is originating from.

I've tried window.location, window.location.replace, window.location.href, 
and self.location.

```
myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.href = "example.tk";
});
```

I want the website to change from the url it is to example.tk, how would I do that if the example.tk does not have a certified https tag?

Comment: Why can't you use `http://example.tk` ?

Comment: Tell me you mean to forward (or redirect) the url.. Not to overwrite the url bar without redirecting, because that is not possible.

Comment: I mean forward, just I can't do https:// because it is not a valid https certificate or what ever, and the website doesn't load on http for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the website to change from the url it is to example.tk, how would I do that if the example.tk does not have a certified https tag?

It's not quite clear what you mean there. If you mean you want to link to an `https://` resource from an `http://` resource, just be explicit:

```
window.location.href = "http://example.tk";
// ---------------------^^^^^^^
```

If you mean, you want to use the same protocol as the current page (`http:` or `https`), you can use a *protocol-relative URL*:

```
window.location.href = "//example.tk";
// ---------------------^^
```

That will use whatever the protocol of the current page is. On `http://example.com`, it will link to `http://example.tk`. On `https://example.com`, it will link to `https://example.tk`.

Hover the link in this snippet to see it in action (no need to click):

```html
<a href="//example.tk">hover this link</a>
```